# Magento and M2E - How to change max execution conficuration value

Tags: magento, configuration, synchronization, execution, m2e

I have a Magento run website and have used M2E pro to manage inventory quantities across Amazon and my website. The quantities aren't syncing and it looks like this is because my max execution configuration value is set at 30 seconds whereas as M2E needs a minimum of 360 seconds.

I've spent hours going through all the options in Magento and can't find where I'd change this setting.

Please can you help?

Thanks a lot indeed

Answer (score 0):

This Magento DevDocs page can be useful: [Magento DevDocs - Changing max_execution_time PHP and web server](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_70pct.html#all-web-servers-and-varnish)